# can't open .xlsx files with Stata any more

Tags: stata, xlsx

I am using Stata 12. Since updating to Excel 2013, I suddenly can't import `.xlsx` files into Stata any more. `.xls` or `.csv` still work fine.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: I've experienced this problem several times with Stata 12 and `.xlsx` files. I don't bother too much, because, as noted by Nick, it's an old version. If possible, I just convert the `.xlsx` to `.xls` or `.csv`, and it usually works fine after that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Since I'm collaborating with a lot of excel users, and since .xlsx is their main file type I wouldn't want to create too many versions of a file. Do you know what driver Stata uses to access xlsx files? It should also be possible to access it with ODBC and the right drivers, no?

Answer (score 3):

Note that Stata 12 was issued in 2011. The current version of Stata at the time of writing is 14.1. Expect that http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/history-of-stata/ will be updated beyond the time of writing.

The help inside Stata 12 says this

> `import excel` and `export excel` look at the file extension, `.xls` or `.xlsx`, to determine which Excel format to read or write. For performance, `import excel` imposes a size limit of 40 MB for Excel 2007/2010 (`.xlsx`) files.  Be warned that importing large `.xlsx` files can severely affect your machine's performance.

Hence it seems that size may be an issue, but more crucially that Stata 12 does not purport to support Excel 2013 insofar as that may have changed the `.xlsx` file format.

Disclaimer: I am fairly experienced with Stata, but emphatically no kind of Excel expert.